# Rewriting urls back and forth using mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Maybe it will seem a very simple question, my website's url are awfully written, so I want to rewrite them. So I am preparing to activate mod_rewrite. The question is the following:

Suppose my url switches from `site_url/index.php?page=mypage&type=mytype` to `site_url/mypage/mytype`, what will happen if one refresh the page, is it necessary to put in the .htaccess file the converse process for proceeding to rewriting ?

Comment: How do you want to rewrite? What comes as URL from the browser and how should it look like internally?

Comment: @OlafDietsche I want this url site_url.index.php?page=mypage&type=mytype to be displayed as site_url/mypage/mytype, so I want to know what is happening when I refresh the page site_url/mypage/mytype, and what is happening when I make a get request with this same url which my code's routes aren't supporting

Comment: The URL never "switches" from `site_url/index.php?page=mypage&type=mytype` to `site_url/mypage/mytype`, is the other way around and I think that's the reason for the confusion. The first step is entering `site_url/mypage/mytype` in the browser's address bar. It is the URL displayed all the time, with a path that doesn't even have to exist. The next step is capturing that request with mod_rewrite directives, to silently map it to an existing  resource like a PHP file. This operation is hidden and is triggered by the "pretty" URL, not the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a combination of redirect and rewriting. A draft outline of URL rewriting process would be:

- If URL contains `.php`, 301/302 redirect the request to its SEO friendly version. This will change the address in browser address bar.
- If SEO friendly URL was requested, rewrite it to its PHP version. This will not change the address in browser address bar.

Here is a *very basic* example of rewrite rules that do both of the above:

```
#
# redirect /index.php?page=somepage&type=sometype to friendly url
# 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\w+)&type=(\w+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1/%2? [R,L]

#
# rewrite /somepage/sometype to index.php
# 
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1&type=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess, you should be making a forward which maps...

```
^/(mypage)/(mytype) to index.php?page=$1&type=$2
```

But the reverse should be left alone. So a direct request to `site_url/index.php?page=mypage&type=mytype` would simply be passed as is.

So, a refresh won't change anything.

Comment: in fact my question is what is happening when  I refresh the page site_url/mypage/mytype, and what is happening when I make a get request with this same url which my code's routes aren't supporting

Comment: @user1611830, what do you mean by "code's routes"? Redirects? Rewrites? Need specificity. Additionally, a refresh is no different than a fresh get request with the exception that browser won't use caches on certain additional items.