# 301 redirect vs mod-rewrite for passing link juice

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a bunch of subcategory index pages on the root level of my site that I inherited from a previous developer with unnested url's like `www.example.com/Category1_Index.php`. My effort is to "friendly-ize" these to `www.example.com/category1/subcategory1/` and so forth.

Here is the mod-write rule I am implementing for the individual url's:

```
RewriteRule   ^category1/subcategory1/?$   Category1_Index.php  [NC]
```

My dilemma is, am I passing the link juice (at least 90% of it) from the old url to the new one this way? Or am I missing something? Is a 301 redirect needed instead? (I'm actually unclear after days of research.)

A couple of things for the record:

1. I implemented these rewrites over a month ago and many of the url's are STILL showing up in Google (leading me to wonder about split link juice value).
2. Our site has lost quite a lot of traffic since implementing.

Comment: You are rewriting, not redirecting. There is no link juice involved.

Comment: So I should 301 redirect instead?

Comment: You should do both. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you changed the URL of your pages from this:

```
www.example.com/Category1_Index.php
```

to this:

```
www.example.com/category1/subcategory1/
```

But you did not redirect your `*.php` URLs to the friendly version. This causes two problems straight away:

- You have duplicate content e.g. Category1_Index.php shows same content as /category1/subcategory1/.
- Or worse if the *.php pages no longer work e.g. they return 404 error.

The latter causes additional problems:

- Users coming to your website following *.php link (from a bookmark, external link or search engine results page) get an error.
- Your old links will be removed from search engine results gradually.

The solution is to 301 redirect *.php pages to their friendly version. This informs search engines and browsers that the address of page has changed. You still need to use URL rewriting.

Comment: I can type in the `*.php` version of the url's and access the pages just fine. Which concerns me. I've tried adding `Redirect 301  /Category1_Index.php http://www.example.com/category1/subcategory1` to htaccess, but that only causes a 404 error. So not sure how to make it work together.

Comment: I am afraid you'll have to debug on your own. It is too much guess work otherwise.

Comment: Try [searching on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect+and+rewrite) or [see if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14295780/87015)